# Whenever I type sudo command on my Kali Linux 2020.1 it doesn't allow me to write further

Tags: linux, sudo, root

Whenever I type `sudo` command on my Kali Linux 2020.1 it doesn't allow me to write further. It just shows this message and it stops reading my commands

```
    We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
    Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.

[sudo] password for kali:
```

Comment: Add your user to the "sudoers" group:  usermod -a -G sudo username  (your username)

Comment: `[sudo] password for kali:` is a *prompt* from `sudo`. The tool expects you to enter password for user `kali` (and hit Enter). It's a common practice not to echo a password. At some (rather low) level of experience this all seems obvious, so excuse me if I'm stating obvious things. But the question is written as if you tried to type a command and expected it to be echoed, instead of typing a password. Interrupt with Ctrl+C, try again and type the password this time. If my diagnosis is wrong then please [edit] and clarify what happens.

Comment: But if my diagnosis is right then consider postponing your adventure with Kali until you gain basic experience with some more friendly distribution. Read [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5361/108618).

Comment: It is true that Kali will not echo the sudo password, but it will operate.  Author: Are you a member of the "sudoers" group?